# Called one action twice in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, redirect

I implement shop in my website. In this site after select products I redirect users to bank and after return of bank come back to one action and the redirect to another action call with **AfterPayment**. In this case  **AfterPayment** action must call only once but when I run project in local **AfterPayment** action called twice.I test this project in server and worked currently.

Statment for redirect in my site after come back from bank :

```
return Redirect("~/" + return_url + "/" + object_id.ToString());
```

AfterPayment action code:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Guest,User,Employee,Admin,SuperAdmin")]

            public ActionResult AfterPayment()
            {
    //
    //
    //
    //
    }
```

what is Problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that your problem is that you have multiple redirects to the AfterPayment action. I think the 3rd party site, the bank, will make the redirect to the first action, which then redirects to the after payment in your above code. Make sure that before you redirect to the bank your controller does not make a redirect to the action that the bank will direct to.

For example: if you are redirecting to a third party service then you must also use a return statement to end that controller action.